# How do spreadsheet from the downloaded file to execute a script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a xls file. I download it on `docs.google.com/file/`. How can it be converted to `docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key = of sript`

How do spreadsheet from the downloaded file to execute a script?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to convert an XLS to a Google Spreadsheet using Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

I convert a xls file with drive

https://gist.github.com/4666836